# How to get a Adwords API token without interaction with a user and browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-ads-api

My question is: How to get the token Adwords without needing to interact with the browser, but only via code

Now I run this code:

```
token = adwords.authorize () do | auth_url | 
  puts "Hit Auth error, please navigate to URL: \ n \ t% s"% auth_url 
  print 'log in and type the verification code:' 
  VERIFICATION_CODE = gets.chomp 
  VERIFICATION_CODE 
end
```

And lap the token that is returned in browser url to liberate access.

Is to do all this using only Ruby code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get offline access to a user's AdWords data,

1. They must grant your app offline permissions
2. You must store and use a refresh token in order to get new access tokens after the initial one expires.

### Asking for Offline Permissions

To ask for offline permissions, simply add the following query parameter to your OAuth2 URL:

```
&access_type=offline
```

Here is an example of a full URL requesting offline permission to the user's AdWords data:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_CALLBACK_URL&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fadwords.google.com%2Fapi%2Fadwords%2F
```

Your client ID will be something like this: `111122223333.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Make sure to properly escape your callback URL before substituting it in.

### Using a Refresh Token

This way, when you get an `access_token` for the account, you will also get a `refresh_token` from Google in the same response.  Store this in your database with the rest of the account's data (including the `access_token`).

Later, when your original access token has expired, you can request a new one by making the following request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?refresh_token=THE_REFRESH_TOKEN&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly Thank you!